# JSOUP: Cannot resolve method title()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup in an android project but it is giving errors. I am using Android Studio. I have added the jsoup jar 1.8.2 to the libs folder and also added the line compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.2.jar') in the build.gradle file. It is strange as I did not face any such issues with Eclipse. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance !!

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
               // Connect to website
                Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
                // Get the html document title
                websiteTitle = document.title();
                Elements description = document.select("meta[name=description]");
                // Locate the content attribute
                websiteDescription = description.attr("content");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

PS: It is also giving the error "Cannot resolve method 'select(java.lang.String)' " for the select method.

Comment: Which error exactly do you get? Please edit the complete stack trace into your question.

Comment: @TimoSta I have added some more info, I am getting errors only where I call the select and title function.

Comment: Have a look at my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error, because a JSoup [`Document`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) has no method `select(String)` as you are trying to call.

Instead, you should [access the head](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#head()), which is represented by an [`Element`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) that allows you to [`select()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String)):

```
Elements description = document.head().select("meta[name=description]");
```

---

On a side note, the explicit cast to `Document` is not necessary:

```
Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/").get();
```

`get()` already returns a `Document`, as you can see [in the cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) or [the API docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#get()).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what about the error cannot resolve method title? Also I casted to document since it was giving a error there too, the error was: Incompatible types: Required: org.w3c.dom.Document, Found: org.jsoup.nodes.Document .

Comment: Which `Document` did you import? Make sure to import `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`. It won't work with `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

Comment: My bad, that was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks though for your time.